# fill in missing values from second or third file (bash)

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following three files:

`list1.txt`

```
AB0001  COG0593
AB0002  COG0592
AB0003  COG1195
AB0005  COG1005
AB0006  COG5621
AB0007  COG4591
AB0008  COG1136
AB0009  COG0071
AB0010  COG3212
```

`list2.txt`

```
AB0001  COG0593
AB0002  COG0592
AB0003  COG1195
AB0004  
AB0005  
AB0006  COG5621
AB0007  COG3127
AB0008  COG1136
AB0009  COG0071
AB0010  COG3212
```

`list3.txt`

```
AB0001  COG0593
AB0002  COG0592
AB0003  COG1195
AB0004  COG5146
AB0005  NOG84439
AB0006  COG5621
AB0007  COG0577
AB0008  COG1136
AB0009  COG0071
AB0010  NOG218375
```

and I want to fill in the missing values (from the first column `AB00[01-10]`) with values from column2 of the other lists, with list1 having the most priority, list2 second most and list3 the least priority. 
So the desired output would be:

```
AB0001  COG0593
AB0002  COG0592
AB0003  COG1195
AB0004  COG5146
AB0005  COG1005
AB0006  COG5621
AB0007  COG4591
AB0008  COG1136
AB0009  COG0071
AB0010  COG3212
```

meaning that list1 should serve as the basis, if a value is missing, take it from list2, if the value is also missing in list2, take it from list3.

Comment: The values are tab separated or white-space separated? and what did you try for yourself?

Comment: they are tab seperated. I tried searching for it, but the only thing I found is `comm`, which is doing the opposite of what I want. The only thing I could imagine is to concatenate the lists in the order 1-2-3, removing duplicate lines with `awk '{ if ($1 in stored_lines) x=1; else print; stored_lines[$1]=1 }'` and sorting. But there must be an easier (preferentially awk) solution to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process the files in reverse order of their precedence and the higher precedence will win. Using `NF>1` ensures that lines with missing values are ignored.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NF > 1 {a[$1] = $2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' list3.txt list2.txt list1.txt | sort
AB0001 COG0593
AB0002 COG0592
AB0003 COG1195
AB0004 COG5146
AB0005 COG1005
AB0006 COG5621
AB0007 COG4591
AB0008 COG1136
AB0009 COG0071
AB0010 COG3212
```

Answer (score 0):

Short ***join*** + ***awk*** combination:

```
join -a2 list1.txt list2.txt | join -a2 - list3.txt | awk '{print $1,$2}' OFS='\t'
```

The output:

```
AB0001  COG0593
AB0002  COG0592
AB0003  COG1195
AB0004  COG5146
AB0005  COG1005
AB0006  COG5621
AB0007  COG4591
AB0008  COG1136
AB0009  COG0071
AB0010  COG3212
```